# Recurrence in analysis of SELECT algorithm

Tags: algorithm, clrs

In CLRS `(2/e, page 191, section 9.3)` the analysis of the `SELECT` algorithm for finding the ith smallest element in an array is presented with the following induction proof:

```
1.  T(n) <= c celing(n/5) + c(7n/10 + 6) + an
2.       <= cn/5 + c + 7cn/10 + 6c + an
3.       = 9cn/10 + 7c + an
4.       = cn + (-cn/10 + 7c + an)
5.       = cn,  when -cn/10 + 7c + an <= 0
```

I understand the algorithm, but two manipulations in the proof have me stumped a bit.

**Question 1**: in line 2, where did the extra c term comee from (second term)? c multiplied through the `(7n/10 + 6)` term gives `7cn/10 + 6c`.

**Question 2**: in line 4, how did we get from `9cn/10` to `cn + (-cn/10 ...)`? Where did the 9 coefficient go?

**This is not homework**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The extra `c` is from `c*celing(n/5)`  - consider `n/5 = 10.2` - then `c * ceiling(n/5) = 11c > cn/5` so we need to add an extra `c`.
2. `9cn/10 = (10-1)cn/10 = 10cn/10 - cn/10 = cn - cn/10 ... = cn + (-cn/10 ...)`

Comment: Amit, thank you. Exactly what I was missing. CLRS is an amazing resource, but sometimes lacks narrative on some of the analysis examples.

Comment: @DavidArsenault: CLRS assumes some mathematical background, it could be tough understanding the book without it I am afraid.. I am happy I could help you out with your problem. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) later on :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for adding more information for the line 2.
We have `ceiling(x) <= x + 1`.Because x is round to the next integer.Assume `m <= x < m+1`,then `ceiling(x) = m+1,x+1 >= m+1`,so we have `ceiling(x) <= x + 1`. And in that case, `c * ceiling(n/5)` must be less than or equal to `c*(n/5+1)`,then you got the extra `c`.